# No jvm.options after having installed JRE 8 and Elasticsearch 7.3.1

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have just installed JRE by using `apt-get install default-jre`

I then installed Elasticsearch by using `apt-get install elasticsearch`

Now, I have to edit the jvm.options file, which should reside under **/etc/elasticsearch/**, but it's not there. I also tried a `find` on jvm.options, to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you just need to create the file?

Comment: No, I have to edit the file that currently sets the JVM options.

Comment: But there might not be one if it is just using default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you got Elasticsearch 7? From what I know, `apt-get install elasticsearch` will get you a very old version of Elasticsearch, and things may be considerably different in that version than in 7.3.1.

My recommendation is to check the Elasticsearch version, and if it's not the one you expect, get one from the official source.